# MySQL Table Indexing incase of queries having multiple Joins

Tags: mysql, join, indexing, query-optimization

I have a query mentioned below taking high query time and is having more than 15k records in demo_request, village, tehsil tables. What should be the best way of indexing the tables. Should i use multi-column indexing or indexing multiple columns to run the below query faster?

```
    DemoRequest::join('villages','villages.village_id','=','demo_request.village_id','left')
                       ->join('tehsils','tehsils.tehsil_id','=','demo_request.tehsil_id','left')->join('districts','districts.district_id','=','demo_request.district_id','left')
                       ->join('states','states.state_id','=','demo_request.state_id','left')      
                       ->join('products','products.product_id','=','demo_request.product_id','left')
                       ->join('crops','crops.crop_id','=','demo_request.crop_id','left')                           
                       ->join('doctor','doctor.dd_id','=','demo_request.dd_id','left');
```

Comment: To help you with your [tag:query-optimization] question, we need more information. Please [read this](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/query-optimization/info), then [edit] your question.

Comment: Please provide the generated SQL and `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for each table involved.  From those, I can probably advise.